# Updating the month in kendo datetime control based on value entered in the text control

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-datepicker

I am working on MVC application. Trying to the add the months to Kendo MVC Datetimepicker control based on the change event of text box control.
When the user enters the months in the Contract Duration field it should add Priority Date time control.

Could somebody advice how it can be done.

[image]

**Contract Duration in Months**

```
  <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ContractDurationInMonths, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ContractDurationInMonths, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", style = "width:100%" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ContractDurationInMonths, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
```

**Priority Datetime control**

```
<div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Priority, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Priority, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })*@
                        @(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(model => model.Priority)
                          .Name("Priority")
                          .Value("10/10/2011")
                          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 100%" })
                        )
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Priority, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, set the blur() event on your textbox then update the value of datepicker:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#ContractDurationInMonths").blur(function () {
                var date = $("#Priority").data("kendoDatePicker").value();
                var newMonth = date.getMonth() + kendo.parseInt($("#ContractDurationInMonths").val());
                date.setMonth(newMonth);
                $("#Priority").data("kendoDatePicker").value(date);
         });              


    });
</script>
```

Here is an example in js: http://dojo.telerik.com/@sg53719/eseRo